# Design a good C++ wrapper class that wraps around multiple functionalities

Tags: c++, oop, design-patterns, wrapper

I want to design a wrapper class in C++ that implements File transfer using FTP, SFTP.

I have a base class `FileTransfer` (using curl) that is inherited by derived class `FTP`. I need to support SFTP, so I have implemented another derived class `SFTP` that also inherits from `FileTransfer`.

I am making a wrapper class code along the following lines. However, this doesn't look like good design. I am relatively new to OOP, although I have worked on C in the past.

```html
class Wrapper {
  public:
  Wrapper(int m_protocol){
    protocol = m_protocol;
    if (protocol)
      pftp = new FTP();
    else
      psftp = new SFTP();
  }
  
  ~Wrapper() {
    if (protocol)
      delete pftp;
    else
      delete psftp;
  }
  //Function supported by both ftp/sftp
  void do_something(){
    if (protocol)
      pftp->do_something();
    else 
      psftp->do_something();
  }
  
  //FTP specific function
  void use_passive(){
    assert(protocol);
    pftp->use_passive();
  }
  
  //SFTP specific function
  void ssh_key(){
    assert(!protocol);
    psftp->ssh_key();
  }
  
  private:
   int protocol;
   FTP *pftp;
   SFTP *psftp;
};
```

How can I improve this design? How can I avoid the `if (protocol)` check inside every function and improve the code quality? Should I instead use `void` pointers for `psftp` and 'pftp`?

Edit: I am using a wrapper because at a lot of places in the project, existing FTP object is being used and if I use a separate class for SFTP (without a wrapper), I will have to add an `if` check every time to also support SFTP. I don't want to expose the detail (FTP/SFTP) to the caller.

Comment: Why are you using a wraper?

Comment: Do you need the wrapper? Seems like for most of it you can just have a `FileTransfer*` that is either an `FTP*` or an `SFTP*`. Definitely not *both* pointers, and definitely not `void*`.

Comment: I am using a wrapper because at a lot of places in the project, existing FTP object is being used and if I use a separate class for SFTP (without a wrapper), I will have to add an `if` check every time to also support SFTP. I want to make the callers unaware of whether it is FTP or SFTP.

Comment: @MukulGupta The probably better design direction is to use a facade or mixin interface aggregation IMHO.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Everything here can be accomplished easier by just using your base class pointer.

```
FileTransfer* ft;
std::unique_ptr<FileTransfer> ft; // C++11
```

Making one:

```
// should this really be an int?
FileTransfer* factory(int protocol) {
    if (protocol)
        return new FTP;
    else
        return new SFTP;
}

// in C++11 this should be
std::unique_ptr<FileTransfer> factory(int protocol);
```

Doing something:

```
ft->do_something();
```

Doing something specific to one or the other:

```
// this will die if ft is an SFTP
dynamic_cast<FTP*>(ft)->use_passive();

// but you could check it
if (FTP* ftp = dynamic_cast<FTP*>(ft)) {
    ftp->use_passive();
}

// or perhaps even better, make a default virtual that does nothing
virtual void FileTransfer::use_passive() { }

void FTP::use_passive() override { // whatever }

ft->use_passive();
```

Deleting:

```
// make sure FileTransfer::~FileTransfer() is virtual!!
delete ft;
```

Comment: Thanks. Making virtual member functions in `FileTransfer` makes more sense. Using dynamic_cast, the callers will have to repeatedly create pointers to `FTP`/`SFTP`.

Comment: Let us suppose, instead of returning `void` `use_passive` returned an int (`int (){}`), this gives error `FileTransfer::use_passive must return a value`. I can't make this a pure virtual function since that would make the class Abstract and I will have to implement `use_passive` in SFTP class as well. What could be done to prevent this?

Answer (score 2):

All you need is [polymorphism](http://www.cplusplus.com/doc/tutorial/polymorphism/) using a pointer to `FileTransfer`, making `do_something()` and the `~FileTransfer()` destructor virtual functions (i.e. you invoque the function on the base object pointer, and the object will call the right function depending on its real class).

The remaining question is only about the construction of your object based on the protocol.  The correct term would not be "wrapper"  but "[factory](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Factory_method_pattern)" (design pattern).  This could be realized by a static member function of the FileTransfer.